# How to determine optimal cutoff for a continous variable after k fold repeated cross validation

Tags: r, r-caret, roc

I want to determine the optimal cutoff for a continuous variable to determine a binary variable. Since my original data only contains approximately 200 samples I am using 10-fold repeated (n =3) cross-validation from `caret` to reduce overfitting. I have split my data into two partitions (70 %/30 %) for training and testing the model respectively.

For the sake of simplicity and reproducibility I have used the "psa" data from the `AROC` package to illustrate what I have done so far. Here I want to determine the optimal cut-off value of marker1 to classify patients as having prostate cancer. Age is also added to the regression model as a covariate.

```
library(AROC)
library(caret)
library(pROC)
data("psa")

psa <- psa %>% dplyr::mutate(cancer = ifelse(status == 1,"Yes","No"))
psa$cancer <- factor(psa$cancer)

##Split data
set.seed(1111)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = psa$status, p = .70, list = FALSE)
training <- psa[ inTrain,]
testing <- psa[-inTrain,]

##Train model
tc <- caret::trainControl("repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3, savePredictions="final", classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary) 

mod1 <- caret::train(cancer ~ marker1 + age,
                      data      = training,
                      method    = "glm",
                      family    = "binomial",
                      metric    = "ROC",
                      trControl = tc)

##Predict on testing data
mod1pred <- predict(mod1, newdata=testing, type="prob")

##ROC on training data
my_roc <- pROC::roc(testing$cancer, mod1pred[[2]])

## Find coordinates for optimal threshold based on Youden index
ci_coordinates <- ci.coords(my_roc, x="best", best.method = "youden", best.policy = "random", transpose = TRUE)
ci_coordinates$threshold ## 0.269
```

As far as I understand this cutoff point is the threshold to determine the probability of a patient having prostate cancer or not in mod1pred and not the cutoff point of marker1. How can I go from this to determine the cutoff point for marker1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly. You built a model based on marker1 + age, and now you want a threshold on marker1 only? If so you may want to look at the following question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/67560/36682

Comment: My question is similar as I want to find the threshold/cutoff point for only one of my to covariates. However, in the question in the link they used the raw data to calculate the cutoff point. In my case I am using predicted values after k-fold cross validation, so it does not answer my question.

Comment: Then if you want a cutoff for only marker1, why do you do a model with marker1 + age? I still don't get this.